# Android O (OPP3.170518.006): Why is there a delay when changing System Settings?

Tags: android-permissions, android-8.0-oreo

I have migrated my Android application try Android O (26).

I have enrolled my supported device in the Android Beta Program, and I am testing on a Google PIXEL XL (OPP3.170518.006)

Functionality within my application requires "Display over other apps".

The process flow is as follows:-

1). User attempts to employ a feature that requires "Display over other apps" and it hasnt been granted.

2). The Activity requests the permission as follows:-

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_MANAGE_OVERLAY_PERMISSION,                            Uri.parse("package:" + getPackageName()));
startActivityForResult(intent, RC_PERMISSION_MANAGE_OVERLAY_PERMISSION);
```

3). within `onActivityResult` I check the permission was granted by the user and start my associated process.

This sequence of events worked fine until migrating to Android O.

The only way I can get this to work now is to use a Handler with postDelay of 3 seconds from within onActivityResult() to start my associated process.

How can I detect the granted permission immediately and not have to wait for 3 seconds?

I have developed the following research application to illustrate this issue

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_physical);

    img = findViewById(R.id.spring_button);
    img.setOnClickListener(this);

    Log.d(TAG, "onCreate: " + Settings.canDrawOverlays(Physical.this));
}

@Override
public void onClick(View view) {

    final Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_MANAGE_OVERLAY_PERMISSION, Uri.parse("package:" + getPackageName()));
    startActivityForResult(intent, RC_PERMISSION_MANAGE_OVERLAY_PERMISSION);

}

@Override
protected void onPostCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Log.d(TAG, "onPostCreate: " + Settings.canDrawOverlays(Physical.this));
}

@Override
protected void onPostResume() {
    super.onPostResume();
    Log.d(TAG, "onPostResume: " + Settings.canDrawOverlays(Physical.this));
}

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    Log.d(TAG, "onStart: " + Settings.canDrawOverlays(Physical.this));
}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    Log.d(TAG, "onStop: " + Settings.canDrawOverlays(Physical.this));
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    Log.d(TAG, "onDestroy: " + Settings.canDrawOverlays(Physical.this));
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    super.onBackPressed();
    Log.d(TAG, "onBackPressed: " + Settings.canDrawOverlays(Physical.this));
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    Log.d(TAG, "onPause: " + Settings.canDrawOverlays(Physical.this));
}

@Override
protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
    super.onNewIntent(intent);
    Log.d(TAG, "onNewIntent: " + Settings.canDrawOverlays(Physical.this));
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    Log.d(TAG, "onResume: " + Settings.canDrawOverlays(Physical.this));
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    switch (requestCode) {
        case RC_PERMISSION_MANAGE_OVERLAY_PERMISSION:
            Log.d(TAG, "onActivityResult: " + Settings.canDrawOverlays(Physical.this));
            break;
    }
}
```

The Logcat output is as follows:-

```
D/Physical: onCreate: true
D/Physical: onStart: true
D/Physical: onPostCreate: true
D/Physical: onResume: true
D/Physical: onPostResume: true

D/Physical: onPause: true
D/Physical: onStop: false
D/Physical: onActivityResult: false
D/Physical: onStart: false
D/Physical: onResume: false
D/Physical: onPostResume: false
```

My application has been granted the "`Display over other apps`" permission, e.g. the toggle switch associated with "`Allow display over other apps`" is `ON` for the entire time these logs were being produced.

So why does the call to `Settings.canDrawOverlays(Physical.this)` return false in `onStop`, `onActivityResult`, `onStart`, `onResume`, and `onPostResume`?

Comment: Have you found the solution for this problem yet?

Comment: @Emmanuel, yes, put a Thread.sleep() to pause the activity restarting